# Android Studio - going to "Android" file tree format from "project" file tree format results in showing "gradle scripts" only

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm importing from Bitbucket and am experiencing the issue.  There are also no run configurations available. Do any Android gurus have an idea?

Thank you

-T

[image]

edit run config:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Different views will show and group your project files differently in Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEs.  I think if you choose "Files", you will see all project files, and the actual directories in which they exist.

If this is a project you downloaded from bitbucket, you will most likely have to build the project yourself, and that is why you only see gradle scripts in the project view.  You will also most likely have to create your own Run configurations.

Developers usually only upload the source files-- it's up to the end users downloading the project to build it themselves to generate the build files.

You could try creating and running your own "Android" Run configuration, and see where the build breaks, patch the current build failure + rerun.  Rinse and repeat.  Sorry for the bad news-- I've been frustrated in the past getting Android projects from github running for the same reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  I just updated my post with a screen shot.  Am I on the right track?  Also, when I try making an Android run configuration, no modules show up for me to select.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you're on the right track-- when you try to create an Android run configuration, do you see any place to specify your Android SDK version/directory?  Also, can you give any additional details about the project?  Does the project have any additional targets other than android (eg. ios-moe, desktop, etc)?

Comment: I went ahead and added another screenshot of the edit config screen.  There are no modules in the drop down and the other options are generic (nothing specifying SDK).  I believe this is strictly for android phone and tablet.  Thank you for your help and persistence :)

Comment: You're editing the "default" configurations-- you want to create a "New" configuration!  Click on the plus button "+" at the top left of the window to create a new Run configuration, then you will be able to select the class to run.  Click the "+" button.
https://imgur.com/a/2EtZAiF

Comment: I've tried that.  The screen looks exactly the same.  Default APK, Artifact, and Nothing are my only options under deploy

Comment: You want "Default APK" under deploy, assuming that you want to build the app and put it on an app store.  This will generate the APK file (eg. <your_app_name>.apk) which is the file you would upload to the app store (eg. Google Play, Amazon Underground, etc.)

If there is no option to select SDK version or main class, try running the configuration after you create it and see what happens.  Maybe Android Studio automatically searches for common project structures.